# check for text in a file on a remote machine

Tags: powershell

I am using a powershell to query a file on a remote machines C-drive and if the file exist with status 'imaging completed' it should run other checks.

```
$filetofind = Get-Content C:\Image.log

#Get the list down to just imagestatus and export
foreach ($line in $filetofind)
    {
    $file = $line.trim("|")
    echo $file >> C:\jenkins\imagestatus.txt
    }
```

But when I run below commands I am getting the error. 
Can anyone help ?

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Image.log' because it does not exist.
    At line:18 char:15
    + $filetofind = Get-Content C:\Image.log
    +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Image.log:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: use test-path to ensure that file is there

Comment: I want to make sure file is there and need to read the file to check the status updated in image.log file to proceed with other checks. How that can be fixed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test-Path` will check if a file exists, and `Select-String` can be used to search the file for a string, using the `-Quiet` param will make the command return `True` if the string is found, rather than returning each line in the text file that includes the string.

Then using both commands in simple if statements to check their status:

```
$file = "C:\Image.log"
$searchtext = "imaging completed"

if (Test-Path $file)
{
    if (Get-Content $file | Select-String $searchtext -Quiet)
    {
        #text exists in file
    }
    else
    {
        #text does not exist in file
    }
}
else
{
#file does not exist
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To check the file on multiple computers you need to use a `foreach` loop to run the code against each computer separately. The below assumes you have one hostname per line in hostnames.txt.

```
$hostnames = Get-Content "C:\hostnames.txt"
$searchtext = "imaging completed"

foreach ($hostname in $hostnames)
{
    $file = "\\$hostname\C$\GhostImage.log"

    if (Test-Path $file)
    {
        if (Get-Content $file | Select-String $searchtext -quiet)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostname: Imaging Completed"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "$hostname: Imaging not completed"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$hostname: canot read file: $file"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James. its work well locally.But when i tried the same remotely its not working. This is how                                                                  $file = "C:\GhostImage.log"
$searchtext = "Imaging Completed:"
$hostname = Get-Content 'C:\hostnames.txt

if (Test-Path $file)
{
    if (Get-Content -$hostname $file | Select-String $searchtext -Quiet)
    {
        echo 'text exists in file'
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'text does not exist in file'
    }
}
else
{
echo 'file does not exist'
}

Comment: `Get-Content` cannot except a hostname like that, see my edit.