# How to find text in file located in remote-server folder?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, file-find

I need to create an easy PowerShell script to find the text in to the files.

I used this script code:

```
Select-String -Pattern "TextToFind" -Path \\ServerName\C$\Folder_I\Folder_II\*.txt
```

But It not work well, this code work only if the folder is located in my machine.  On the remote machine, I got this error:

```
is missing the terminator CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:String) [], ParseException FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Is this the right syntax to link the remote folder?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363111/check-for-text-in-a-file-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: What is the error that you get? Please edit your post and show the error.

Comment: @EBGreen Probably access denied considering his syntax is fine.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That would be my guess. Just wanted to confirm since that would make it not a dupe. Well, at least not a dupe of the linked question...

Comment: Hi @EBGreen  this is error message _is missing the terminator_ _CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:String) [], ParseException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString_

Comment: First, that doesn't look like the entire error message and second ***"...Please edit your post and show the error."***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about running it on the remote server. PowerShell remoting will need to have been setup.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'ServerName' -Command Select-String -Pattern "TextToFind" -Path C:\Folder_I\Folder_II\*.txt
```

@ulisses added this. Yes, it works, but it requires the file to be sent over the network. Using `Invoke-Command` runs the command on the remote machine. That is generally faster than reading the file across the network.

Work fine too this command line:

```
Select-String -Pattern 'TextToFind' -Path \\ServerName\C$\folder_I\Folder_II\*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks al lot @lit. Nice Answer, only question, When I run this command not appear the list of file where the _TextToFind_ exist. (I'm shure the text exist in file), It return at new void command line, like "_PS C:\Users\Nameuser>_"

Comment: After I looking PowerShell documentation (and activated remote **Enable-PSRemoting –force** about _https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx_) work well. Thanks @lit for yor time.